# Communication between MainPage and UserControl

Tags: xaml

Im trying to make changes to my MainPage from a Usercontroll. If we take the following scenario:

MainPage contains the UC and a textblock:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">        

    <local:uc></local:uc>
    <TextBlock Text="Hide me from the UC!" />

 </Grid>
```

The `UserControll` only cotains a button:

```
<Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" />
```

Here is the CodeBehind for the `UserControll`

```
public sealed partial class uc : UserControl
    {
        public uc()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do stuff to element in MainPage
        }
    }
```

So my question is if its possible for me to get a hold of the `TextBlock` thats located in the `MainPage` from my `Usercontroll`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the element in the page that you'd like to manipulate from within the UserControl will always be a `TextBlock`, you can pass a reference to it to the UserControl. To do so, you create a dependency property of type `TextBlock` within the UserControl and store the reference in a private field, so that you can access it from within the button's event handler:

```
private TextBlock _myText;

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyText", typeof (TextBlock), typeof (uc), new PropertyMetadata(default(TextBlock), PropertyChangedCallback));

public TextBlock MyText
{
    get { return (TextBlock) GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
}

private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var self = dependencyObject as uc;
    var element = args.NewValue as TextBlock;
    if (self != null && element != null)
        self._myText = element;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_myText != null)
        _myText.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

In this case, you'd bind the `TextBlock` to the UserControl like:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="SomeTextBlock"/>
<local:uc MyText="{Binding ElementName=SomeTextBlock}"/>
```

Of course you can also use a dependency property of type `UIElement` to be more flexible.

Alternatively, define an event within the UserControl that fires when the button is clicked, and let the page itself decide what to do in that case (e.g., hide some `TextBlock`):

```
public partial class uc : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler OnButtonClicked;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnButtonClicked != null)
            OnButtonClicked(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        uc.OnButtonClicked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            SomeTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good and explanatory answer!
Being new to this kind of code the second alternative is more understandale to me.  The only thing that bugs me a little is that I have to create a new instance of the uc in the mainpage. Im trying to work with mvvm to avoid this. Is it possible to use similar code in an MVVM approach?
But you did answer my question very well so i´ll accept this as an answer.

Comment: Since the `uc`'s purpose is to display a button and show/hide a text element (which both clearly belongs to View logic), I don't see how creating a `uc` instance within the page (which belongs to the View layer) would be in conflict with MVVM.